# Calculating the correlation between two time based series of events

Tags: algorithm, math, time-series, correlation

I need some help identifying the mathematical technique that calculates the correlation between two series of time-events. I think I need to calculate a Cross-correlation but I'm no expert in statistics.

Imagine someone suspects a link between taking a pill and a subsequent headache. He logs in his diary when he takes the pill and strength of pill (magnitude scale 1-5), and he logs when he gets a headache and its magnitude.

Series S (for stimulus, columns Date, Magnitude (1-5))

17-08-2016 14:50: 1,

18-08-2016 14:50: 4, ...

Series R (for response)

20-08-2016 14:50: 1,

21-08-2016 14:50: 4, ...

Lets assumed we know (as seen from that data) we know the symptom lags the drug 3 days, so elapse times can overlap. What is the mathematically technique and/or algorithm for calculating that correlation if the sampling periods are varied?

Comment: I believe you are correct about needing to compute a Cross-Correlation.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to do some kind of padding so that the sampling lines-up (for cases where the difference between dates are large)? Also, wouldn't normalised cross-correlation be a better technique?